# Heroku Django DEBUG Setting not applied

Tags: django, heroku

I currently have a running production Django application on Heroku. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to turn off the `DEBUG` setting on Heroku. Turning it off locally works fine, but when pushed to Heroku (after `heroku config:set DEBUG=False`), it doesn't apply.

The error pages are still the default `DEBUG` ones instead of the 404, 403, and 500 templates in our template root.

I have also tried using a `DJANGO_DEBUG` setting in case there were any environment conflicts with `DEBUG`, and casting the result to a boolean in the settings file. `heroku config` shows the settings in the environment are correct. This is on Django 1.3, Heroku Cedar.

Any tips or solutions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Does your django settings.py file even look in the environment?

It does not, by default, care about anything you've set in the environment (via "config:set"). If you're "casting" the environment to a boolean, make sure you're casting it correctly. bool('False') is still True.

It's simplest just to detect if the environment variable exists so you don't have to worry about type casting or specific formats of the configuration.

`DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)`

To disable debug, *remove* the variable from the environment instead of trying to type cast... it just seems much more reliable and fool proof. `config:unset DEBUG`

Comment: Yep, just about anything different between staging and production is drawing from the environment. I'll try just removing it altogether.

Comment: Awesome, just removing it instead of setting it to False worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! So I'm guessing the type casting wasn't working bool('False')  perhaps.

Comment: I don't think so, because it wasn't working before I tried casting. Originally I had DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False), and had set it to False in the environment, and it didn't work. I think just forcing the default is the solution, though I'm still puzzled as to why it wasn't working before.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. You are not doing any type casting at all: Typing config:set DEBUG=False is equal to settings django's DEBUG variable to `DEBUG='False'` which is still `bool(DEBUG) == True`. Core distinction is the difference between python boolean False vs 'False'.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually finally got it working all around, by using `bool(os.environ.get('DEBUG', ''))`. So True is any string, and False is an empty string.

Removing it from the environment worked to disable it, but only because it wasn't possible to enable it with `DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)` set.

Comment: Just leaving this here for future googlers. This module can be used to avoid casting environment variables

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the environment variable is not a boolean, rather a string.
So do place below line in `settings.py`

`DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE') == 'True')`