# django DEBUG=False still runs in debug mode

Tags: django

I'm having issues setting my `DEBUG = False` on my deployed server (on heroku).

I don't believe I've seen this before, but setting debug to false is not getting rid of debug mode for my project. This means that when there are 500 errors it shows the error, and 404 errors are showing all my urls.

What's strange is that when i log into the server and run get the setting value from `django.conf import settings settings.DEBUG` it shows as False, which is what I set it to for the production server. `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` is also set to False.

I don't know I've ever seen this before where `DEBUG = False` but it's still acting in debug mode. Any ideas?

#### EDIT:

Thought I'd put this little note too because it's very common for people to be getting 500 or 400 errors when switching debug to False. I am not getting any errors, my project is just acting like it's in DEBUG mode.

```
# settings/dev.py
from .base import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

if not DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

SECRET_KEY = 'localsecret1234123412341234'


# settings/prod.py
from .base import *

import dj_database_url, os

DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG", False)
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.com']
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY"]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

Comment: You may wish to provide your full settings.py file (minus any secrets); also, provide a step-by-step description of how you set DEBUG to false and attempt to make it take effect.

Comment: Are you running a local and production settings file?   There's a couple of things - first you'll need to provide your settings file(s) - and have you reset once you've made the change to DEBUG?  Depending on your configuration on Heroku, it may not automatically reset whatever's serving the Django app.  Lastly, are there any environment variables being used?  It's possible that's overriding your settings file binding.

Comment: added the dev/prod settings. As far as i know heroku is resetting. I didn't know it was possible not to, every time I upload any changes they take effect.

If you need to see the full settings/base.py let me know, but the thing is that when i go into ./manage.py shell it's showing that debug is False.

Comment: @JerryStratton i set `DEBUG=False` in the active settings file and then verify that it is actually set to False in the manage.py shell. Also going to a page i know returns a 404 and seeing if it returns my 404.html template or shows me all the urls

Comment: @Withnail i tried manually restarting with `heroku restart` and same behavior

Comment: Hmm.  That all looks right - what do you get if you run `printenv` from the heroko (not django) shell - is there a reference to your `DEBUG` setting there?  I still have a feeling that an EnvVariable is at play here.

Comment: yeah, and also if i just hardcode False it has same behavior

Comment: @Withnail actually that was it, I had tried hardcoding debug before, but apparently i didn't properly try it. It was an issue with the setting being a string rather than boolean (since the env variable is string not bool)

Comment: Glad it helped! I've put a fuller answer as I see Q's like this, and hopefully the answer will help someone else. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put this as an actual answer for people that come after.

There are three main areas that this can happen, where 'this' is basically:

> I've changed something in my settings, but it doesn't seem to be reflected in the operation of my app!

1. Server hasn't been reset after code changes made.
2. Local and Dev settings haven't overridden/or are overriding in unexpected ways
3. A local Environment Variable is overriding the attempt at hardcoding it

On Heroku, as in this example, Environment Variables [are set this way.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) A more general guide to using them in [Linux enviroments is available here.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)

Using an example from the question, you can see the environment variables being used in:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY"]
```

This uses the os library to go out to the system, and check for an environment variable called `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`.

A better example is the:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get("DEBUG", False)
```

This is good because it tries to get it from the environment, and if that fails, uses the second value in the tuple as the default: in this case, False.

During the course of debugging, you can hunt down your settings using `printenv` from the linux shell, which will print out all of the available EnvVars.  If they're not there, you can set them in the format:

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`

In this instance, it's probably better to unset the environment variable, rather than typecasting, [as per this related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258290/heroku-django-debug-setting-not-applied)

Answer (score 31):

The root cause of issue - False translated to `'False'` string not bool.

Used next solution (*settings.py*):

```
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', False) == 'True'
```

i.e.: in this case `DEBUG` will set to (bool) `True`, only if the environment variable is explicitly set to `True` or `'True'`.

Good luck configuring! :)

Comment: from environment, you read the DEBUG value as string, as Daniel wrote in his answer, the value of your environment variable is `'False'`, which is not the boolean type, `False`. Worth to double check, I think.

Comment: Works great in configmap with Kubernetes.

Comment: Correct answer, tried every fix on internet nothing worked, this explanation is much needed. Thank you

Comment: @Bharath You're welcome! I'm happy that my answer has helped you!

Comment: For anyone **using conf.json file**, the syntax is `DEBUG = config['DEBUG'] == "True"`

Answer (score 9):

As a note for others: I had the same problem; I configured my production website on a VM with gunicorn and nginx, following the tutorial for ubuntu 16.04 from [the digital ocean documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I wasn't able to turn off the debug mode, even when restarting the nginx systemd's service: the solution was to restart also the gunicorn service:

```
# systemctl restart nginx gunicorn
```

Answer (score 6):

If somebody is using `python-decouple` for env variables and having trouble with DEBUG you have to use this line to retrieve booleans:

```
from decouple import config
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks @jturi, this finally solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

This ended up being an issue with the config variable being "False" instead of `False`, and so debug wasn't properly set to the boolean value. Shoutout to @WithNail for helping get to the answer

Answer (score 3):

DEBUG takes Boolean value.

The os.environ.get("DEBUG", False) returns string value.

All the string value while typecasting return True.
That's why the DEBUG is True.

```
 print(bool(os.environ.get("DEBUG", False))) # output: True
 print(bool("False"))  # output: True
 print(bool(""))  # output: False
```

To solve issue in heroku don't set any value to config var. it will return null string and after typecasting it will return False:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you use the module `decouple` (`pip install python-decouple`) make sure you cast DEBUG to a bool. Thus settings.py should have the following line:

```
from decouple import config

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
```

where in the `.env` file

```
DEBUG = False # or True
```

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this problem as I was loading the debug setting from an environment variable `DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG_MODE'))`.

This set the DEBUG value as a string, not a boolean.

To fix this, I hardcoded `DEBUG = False` in my prod settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error that OTREE_PRODUCTION=1 gives error 500 on Heroku. What I did is to make a new app (Note to change Heroku stack to make it compatible with your Python version) , upload codes to this new app, and set OTREE_PRODUCTION=1 for this new app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue & none of the solutions worked. My error stems from the the server configuration. `I have multiple apps served by NGINX` & `GUNICORN`. One of the apps is linked with the `default server`.

This means that any request not matching any of the IP:port listening pair server blocks is served by the `default server`. While debugging I happened to have set the settings.py of the app linked with the default server block to `DEBUG=True` & **forgot** to set it back to `DEBUG=False`.

So bringing settings.py of the default app's server block back to `DEBUG=False`, solved the issue.