# Django debug mode hags even if DEBUG= False

Tags: django, debugging

I'm having problems with disabling DEBUG mode from Django.
The main website still shows up as well as the /api debug calls.

Before I wrote, I double checked all the solutions from: [django DEBUG=False still runs in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617046/django-debug-false-still-runs-in-debug-mode) and the others posts, as well as the official documentation.

The app is running on App Engine.

This is my main configuration:

main.py

```
from apps.wsgi import application as app
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.dev")
    DEBUG = False
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

settings.dev

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("loading settings dev.py")
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DOCS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "docs", "html")
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

Comment: Have you checked `print('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' in os.environ)` output before `setdefault` (line 6) to make sure that the `setdefault` takes its main action?

Comment: I did try, to load it manually from the main.py, so I deleted manage.py.
Application is running directly from apps/wsgi.py the settings are populated correctly however the main page of DEBUG is still showing up... Even if DEBUG is set as False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that App Engine reads the `main.py` file and ignored `manage.py` in general.
After applying the settings to `main.py`, everything worked as it should.

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", os.getenv('ENV'))
application = get_wsgi_application()
```