# django-simple-captcha breaking heroku deploy

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm using django-simple-captcha and it's working fine locally.  The page it's on gives a 500 error once deployed to Heroku (the only log output I get is (`2017-02-11T13:26:07.367450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact/" host=fathomless-harbor-1234.herokuapp.com request_id=37555c3c-c468-40cb-a142-c7dd04519e2c fwd="73.163.191.194" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=83ms status=500 bytes=386`).

I ran the `./manage.py test captcha` and got three failed tests, all of which have the similar error of `File "/Users/pmn/.virtualenvs/within/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 43, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
TemplateDoesNotExist: captcha_test/image.html`

I am on django 1.9.6 and django-simple-captcha 0.5.3

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

from captcha.fields import CaptchaField


class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    contact_name = forms.CharField()
    contact_email = forms.EmailField()
    contact_phone = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    cc_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)
    captcha = CaptchaField(required=True)

    def send_email(self):
        contact_name = self.data["contact_name"]
        contact_phone = self.data["contact_phone"]
        contact_email = self.data["contact_email"]
        content = self.data["content"]

        template = get_template("contact.txt")

        context = {
            "contact_name": contact_name,
            "contact_phone": contact_phone,
            "contact_email": contact_email,
            "content": content,
        }

        content = template.render(context)
        subject, from_email, to = "Inquiry", contact_email, "jason@email.com"
        cc_address = contact_email if "cc_me" in self.data else None
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            subject,
            content,
            from_email,
            ["jason@email.com"],
            cc=[cc_address],
            headers={"Reply-To": contact_email}
        )
        email.send()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

(Note if I comment out the two captcha lines, the page loads on the deploy)

Comment: Side note, if there are more detailed logs available, I'd be grateful if you could point them out.

Comment: Do you have any uncommitted changes to `settings.py` locally? Or are you using different settings on Heroku? It sounds like the app may not be in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Nope, and it's definitely in `INSTALLED_APPS`.  I should clarify that although it works locally, running the test suite locally does result in the three failed tests, all with the above error.  Doesn't seem to affect anything locally though.

Comment: You're going to have to dig into that HTTP 500 error. Can you enable debug mode on Heroku?

Comment: @Chris I haven't found any way to do that--are you suggesting I just sent `DEBUG=True` and push that to production?  I was led to believe that would cause a black hole or something and doom humanity.

Comment: That would work, but it's not a very good solution. Heroku advocates [separating configuration from code and loading configuration from the environment](https://12factor.net/config). Then you can enable or diable debug mode by simply [setting an environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258290/heroku-django-debug-setting-not-applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the database migrations had not been run on Heroku.  `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` and `heroku run python manage.py migrate` fixed it.