# Django DEBUG weirdness in IIS: DEBUG=False still runs in debug mode

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, environment-variables

Summary: My site is running in DEBUG mode even though settings are set to DEBUG = False.

FYI, I've researched this and found some excellent responses and testing ideas in these related questions (none of which helped, even though logically they SHOULD have): [django DEBUG=False still runs in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617046/django-debug-false-still-runs-in-debug-mode)
 and [Heroku Django DEBUG Setting not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258290/heroku-django-debug-setting-not-applied)

---

**IIS FastCGIHandler environmental variable:**

Name = `DJANGO_DEBUG`
Value = `False`

*Note: Removing this environmental variable causes a 500 error regardless of setting in production.py.*

**settings/production.py:**

Different scenarios tried in settings/production.py using env variable set to False in my FastCGIHandler:

1. `DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', False)`

   - RESULT: Site runs in Debug Mode
2. `DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', False))`

   - RESULT: Site runs in Debug Mode
3. `DEBUG = False` *(hardcode w/o env var)*

   - RESULT: Site doesn't work, returns 500 page and error tracking gives `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/favicon/manifest.json'` which is a very bizarre and misleading error.

---

**Other actions taken:**

- I've checked both the base.py and production.py files for any other references to `DEBUG` or to the `DJANGO_SETTINGS` variable and they are clear. I also searched other .py files that the IIS server interacts with (wsgi.py, manage.py).
- I have even tried setting `DEBUG = False` in the base.py file as well with the same results.
- I installed python-decouple and tried using that.
- I installed django-environ and tried using that (I have another django site running on this server using django-environ to access the environmental variables which works fine.)

---

I've never seen anything like this. The other environmental variables are working fine so it seems to be around this Boolean value. And why wouldn't hardcoding the DEBUG variable in the python settings work???

Any help in figuring out where to look next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are always strings. A non-empty string is always boolean True, even if it contains the string "False".

You would need to compare the value with a string:

```
DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG') == "True")
```

or, just remove the variable from your IIS settings altogether when you want to run in non-debug mode.

The other error is not "bizarre or misleading", but a problem with your static files that you will need to fix before using the ManifestStorage backend in non-debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Daniel. The reason that I say the error is misleading is because there is no error when debug is on.  The static files are found without issue. How would debug mode change this error?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't fix it. Changing my DEBUG statement to match yours still gives me the 500 error. And, I already stated that removing the variable from IIS causes the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

in settings.py:

```
if os.environ.get('DEBUGMODE') == 'True':
    DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUGMODE') == 'True')
else:
    DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DEBUGMODE') != 'False')
```

Now you can only change your variable value in environment files or heroku if you use it